# Transform and convert a List to Set with Guava

Tags: java, collections, guava

Is there a simple way to **convert** and **transform** a List to Set with Guava?

I'd like to use method:

```java
Set<To> result = Sets.transformToSet(myList, new Function<From, To>() {
            public To apply(From item) {
                return convert(item);
            }
        });
```

this is my code, with "tempCollection"

```java
Collection<To> tempCollection = Collections2.transform(myList, new Function<From, To>() {
            public To apply(From item) {
                return convert(item);
            }
        });
Set<To> result = newHashSet(tempCollection );
```

Comment: There isn't anything like this because A) there are different types of sets with different behaviors (e.g. `HashSet` vs. `TreeSet`) and you need to choose which one you want to use, and B) the `transform` methods are lazy views and a `Set` can't be a view of an arbitrary collection without having O(n) `size` and `contains` methods.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Set<To> result = FluentIterable.from(myList)
                               .transform(new Function<From, To>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public To apply(From input) {
                                       return convert(input);
                                   }
                               })
                               .toSet();
```

This creates an ImmutableSet, which does not accept null. So if you want your Set to contain null, you'll have to use another solution, like the one you're currently using.

Note that, if it's the creation of the temporary collection that bothers you, you shouldn't be bothered. No copy is made. The collection is simply a view over the original list.

Comment: if the function might return null, just do a `filter(Predicates.notNull())` after the transform()

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: Except if you *want* to have null in the returned Set. I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: If you don't want an `ImmutableSet`, instead of `toSet()` you could do `copyInto(new HashSet<To>())`, among other things.